# Is this calculation of mining probability using the Bernoulli trial formula accurate?

Tags: blockchain, mining-profitability, proof-of-work

I'm trying to understand the formulas for successfully mining a block (without a pool) based on hashrate over time (i.e. to chart the probability of finding a block at various historical points compared to network hashrate at the time).

It seems like [this post](https://medium.com/@batog/bitcoin-mining-versus-lottery-69d3b46e0f65) is exactly the formula I'm looking for, but it doesn't actually add up. I'm awful at math so I can't tell if I'm missing a step or if the post is wrong. If there's a better/more accurate way of figuring this out, please share, but **I'm specifically interested in learning if this is wrong or not and why.**

It says the probability of being the one to successfully mine a block with 13.5 TH/s and a network hashrate of 11,000,000 TH/s = 0.00000122

Then it says:

> Now, in a month, there are N=6*24*30 mined blocks. To find the probability of winning one award in a month, we use the Bernoulli trial formula
>
> N*p1*(1-p1)^(N-1) = 0.0026

Now when I put that in Excel with N=4320, I get .005243, I only come up with the same answer when I divide N by two for N=2160, but I can't figure out any reason for that to be the case. Am I missing something or is this just a typo? Is this formula even a good way of approximating this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula is a reasonable approximation.  It looks to me like your calculation is right, and the blog author has made an error.

There is a minor inaccuracy in that the number of blocks per month is not fixed at `6*24*30`, but is subject to random variation.  So a slightly improved solution is to work out the average number of terahashes needed for one block (`h = 11000000 * 600`, assuming that the network hash rate is stable and the block difficulty has adjusted accordingly).  Then your probability of winning a block on each of your hashes is `q1 = 1 / h`, and you will perform `M = 12.5 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30` hashes in one month.  If you treat the number of blocks you win as a [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution), the probability of winning one block in a month is given by `λ * exp(-λ)` where `λ = M*q1`.  This yields the slightly larger number 0.005273.